# Cannot open display browser:99, error 1. browser:99: I/O error during selenide tests execution against Firefox browser in Selenoid

Tags: java, docker, selenide, selenoid

I get the next error in my console log during Java Selenide test execution against Firefox browser that is running by Selenoid. This error occurs after aproximately 25 min of normal test execution (4 threads). And occurs every run. Could anyone help please to understand what can be wrong? I suspect some memory problems, but how can I avoid them? Maybe some config of capabilities? thank you in advance

`[x11grab ...] Cannot open display browser:99, error 1. browser:99: I/O error during selenide tests execution against Firefox browser in Selenoid`

config:

````
        selenoidOptions.put("enableVideo", true);
        selenoidOptions.put("enableVNC", true);
        selenoidOptions.put("videoName", getVideoFileName(scenario)); ```

    ```     browser = FIREFOX;
                browserVersion = "115.0";
                FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                options.setCapability("selenoid:options", selenoidOptions);
                browserCapabilities = options;
                break;```
````

Comment: Resolved: There was another video-recorder container run on the same environment. The problem has been solved by removing container